# Distributed training of a GRU network on Spark - PyTorch implementation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pytorch, distributed-computing

I have an implementation of a GRU based network in PyTorch, which I train using a 4 GB GPU present in my laptop, and obviously it takes a lot of time (4+ hrs for 1 epoch). I am looking for ideas/leads on how I can move this deep-learning model to train on a couple of spark clusters instead.

So far, I have only come across this GitHub library called **SparkTorch**, which unfortunately has limited documentation and the examples provided are way too trivial.
https://github.com/dmmiller612/sparktorch

**To summarize**, I am looking for answers to the following two questions:

- *Is it a good idea to train a deep learning model on spark clusters*, since I read at places that the communication overhead undermines the gains in training speed
- *How to convert the PyTorch model* (and the underlying dataset) in order to perform a distributed training across the worker nodes.

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply use PyTorch's distributed instead of spark?

Comment: Yes, I have read and tried PyTorch's Distributed. However, if I understood correctly, it's more concerned with distributing your processes across multiple GPU's (at least the documentation didn't mention anything for the CPU's). I have got 5 nodes (CPUs), each having 4 cores, which I want to utilize to speed up my training.